# How to detect when the delete key is pressed on the keyboard?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, getch, del

I want that when the <kbd>Del</kbd> key is pressed a certain function is called.
How can I achieve that using `getch()` if possible or otherwise some nested `getch()` calls?

Comment: What platform are you programming for? `getch()` is not a portable function and the answer for your question depends on platform.

Comment: I am using windows and i have no problem if the solution will only work on the windows platform

Comment: The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.  _getch() returns 0xE0 if it is an extended key like F1 or Del.  Call _getch() again to get the scancode of the key.  0x53 for the Del key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `_getch()` returns an "escaped" value for cursor and page control keys. For the keypad and the function keys, that is `0` followed by the key code, for other keys it is `224` followed by the key code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define ESC     27
#define ESC1    0
#define ESC2    224

int main()
{
    int d=-1, e=-1;
    printf("Press a key (Esc to quit)\n");
    do {
        d = _getch();  
        if (d == ESC1) {
            e = _getch();  
            printf("%d %d\n", d, e);
        } else if (d == ESC2) {
            e = _getch();  
            printf("%d %d\n", d, e);
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", d);
        }
    } while (d != ESC);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the program and pressing three keys Delete, Del(keypad), Esc produces the output

```
Press a key (Esc to quit)
224 83
0 83
27
```

Of course, Numlock must be Off.

Comment: somehow for me it is -32 not 0 or 224 but overall it works, so thank you!

Comment: @xixhxix note that `_getch()` returns `int` not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for this function kbhit() .It is basically for keyboard hit and look for del key ascii code and match with that .